# IntelliJ IDEA creates signed final apk with no images from /assets

Tags: android, intellij-idea, google-play

I was very happy when I found ability to  create release signed and proguarded apk
in my IntelliJ IDEA 11.
But  created apk is very small ( 6 MB) against 33 MB of
all files in "production\out\mygame"
I guess images from /assets were not included to this final apk.
Or should I upload somehow classes.dex,  mygame.apk.res to GooglePlay?
Thanks.

Comment: Works fine here. Maybe you can share a small sample project to reproduce this problem?

Comment: I added 11 MB file to /assets of  small licensing example. And created final apk is really 11 MB. But when I do the same with my both Libgdx Android projects, I got 6-10MB of code, and no additional 10 MB of /assets. The both projects are uninstallable via sdcard.

Comment: BTW, There is a checkbox f"ile-project structure-facets-android-compiler-include resources to apk". No difference if I check the box or not.

Comment: I will upload sample Libgdx project to show the problem

Comment: As for third libgdx app. Maybe apk contains /assets. It is not installable too.  You can take a look at it at http://www.k-ct.com/temp/Game3_A.zip

Comment: This project has `/assets` properly packaged inside the final apk file. Please revise your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to [export the signed apk](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/export-signed-android-package-wizard.html) from the [provided project](http://www.k-ct.com/temp/Game3_A.zip) and run it on my device. Try to disable Proguard option, it didn't work for me, probably because your project needs different configuration for obfuscation.

The signed APK contains all the images from `/assets`.

Comment: Yes. Apk should be signed. It is a must. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am not right. IntelliJ works okay. It is just impossible to install unsigned apk on device (what I tryed to do). Thanks